# How to order a json file list?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

My goal is to get specific data on many profiles on khanacademy by using their API.

My problem is: in their API, json files have different list orders. It can vary from one to another.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

# here is a list with two json file links:
profiles=['https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959','https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959']

# for each json file, take some specific data out
for profile in profiles:
    print(profile)
    with urlopen(profile) as response:
        source = response.read()
    data = json.loads(source)

    votes = data[1]['renderData']['discussionData']['statistics']['votes']
    print(votes)
```

I expected something like this:

```
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959
100
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959
41
```

Instead I got an error:

```
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959
100
https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitch.py", line 12, in <module>
    votes = data[1]['renderData']['discussionData']['statistics']['votes']
KeyError: 'discussionData'
```

As we can see:

This link `A` is working fine: `https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959`

But this link `B` is not working: `https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959` And that's because in this json file. The list is not in the same order as it is  in the `A` link.

My question is: Why? And how can I write my script to get into account these variation of orders?

There is probably something to do with `.sort()`. But I am missing something.

Maybe I should also precise that I am using python `3.7.2`.

Link A: desired data (yellow) is in the second item of the list (blue):

[image: as we can see in bleu the dictionnary is second here, yellow the desired data]

Link B: desired data (yellow) is in the third item of the list (blue):

[image: as we can see in bleu the dictionnary is third here, yellow the desired data]

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse is it more clear now?

Comment: Much better. Thank you.

Comment: The second link does not contain `discussionData` within `renderData` so you can't get `votes` from it. Is there something else you want to get from these entries or do you just want to ignore the entries that don't contain `discussionData`?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I am not sure why you don't have the `discussionData` within `renderData` in the `B` link. I added some images, do you get the same output?

Comment: Okay I see that now but it is not in the first two `dict`s within that list. What do you want to do with the `dict`s that do not contain it?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I guess to ignore/delete them at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catching exceptions in python doesn't take much overhead unlike other languages so I would recommend the "better ask forgiveness then permission" solution. This will be slightly faster than searching through a `str` for the word `votes` as it will fail instantly if the key is invalid.

```
import requests

urls = ['https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959',
        'https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    result = []
    for item in response:
        try:
            result.append(item['renderData']['discussionData']['statistics']['votes'])
        except KeyError:
            pass # Could not find votes
    print(result)
```

Comment: mine won't fail. It will return an empty list. So not sure mine is slower. try except is a nice approach though.

Comment: Yours won't fail. The reason yours is a tad slower is because of this part `if 'votes' in str(item)`. You are converting a `dict` to a `str` which takes some time and the search (`in`) takes awhile as well.

Comment: That is useful to know+

Comment: @QHarr Though to be fair the time saving isn't significant (~0.05s).

Comment: Every little counts :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `if` to test if `votes` in current index dictionary

```
import requests

urls = ['https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_329989584305166460858587/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959',
        'https://www.khanacademy.org/api/internal/user/kaid_901866966302088310331512/profile/widgets?lang=en&_=190424-1429-bcf153233dc9_1556201931959']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    result = [item['renderData']['discussionData']['statistics']['votes'] for item in r  if 'votes' in str(item)]
    print(result)
```